# How to check authority on submenu items in JHipster

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, security, jhipster

How to check for a certain authority in a submenu. ex. /admin/user-management page can be accessed by a user who has a certain authority.

```
<>
    <MenuItem icon="user" to="/admin/user-management">
      <Translate contentKey="global.menu.admin.userManagement">User management</Translate>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem icon="tachometer-alt" to="/admin/metrics">
      <Translate contentKey="global.menu.admin.metrics">Metrics</Translate>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem icon="tasks" to="/admin/logs">
      <Translate contentKey="global.menu.admin.logs">Logs</Translate>
    </MenuItem>
  </>
```

Answer (score 2):

To get access to the `isAuthenticated` and `isAdmin` props, you have multiple options:

- Pass in the props to the component [from the parent `<Header />` component](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-react/blob/021ce8790692f29ba2d1b476c95517bc4540de67/src/main/webapp/app/shared/layout/header/header.tsx#L55-L57).
- Connect your component to Redux and add the fields as props, like how is done in [app.tsx](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-react/blob/021ce8790692f29ba2d1b476c95517bc4540de67/src/main/webapp/app/app.tsx#L64-L65).

To restrict the paths, even for direct navigation, see the example in [routes.tsx](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-react/blob/021ce8790692f29ba2d1b476c95517bc4540de67/src/main/webapp/app/routes.tsx#L38-L39)